# When MacBook runs out of battery after restart message problem detected occurs

Tags: battery, restart

For some months I have the following problem: After a restart (when my MacBook Pro 2017) runs out of battery, and after having logged in, a message that the computer was shut down unexpectedly occurs. Is this behavior normal?

Does anyone has a similar problem? Do you need more information regarding this problem from me?

With best greetings,
Leon

Comment: Why do you consider this a problem?  It seems to be a normal message.  Your computer shut down, by itself, because you let it run out of power.  That's an unexpected problem.  The message appears accurate to me.

Comment: When it runs out of battery, it looks to the operating system after the restart in the same way as it does when the kernel crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's normal, because before exhausting the battery completely (around 3-5%) it goes into a sleep mode. But if it is completely exhausted, the message it mentions is displayed and allows you to restore what you had previously opened or restart the startup.

Comment: ok because on my Mac book air there does never show up that message, but thanks :)